# Bash startup script which opens a PPP and then executes a delayed command--how?

Tags: multithreading, bash, startup, kde-plasma

I have a bash script I want to run at startup (Kubuntu 11.04) which opens my company's VPN. The VPN client in KDE doesn't like this VPN, so I need to do this manually. It opens a ppp0 connection, and then adds an ip route. Here's the issue: I need to run the pppd call command, and after about 5 seconds, add the ip route. I have the commands just fine, and running these two commands separately in two different shell sessions works dandy; my problem is that the pppd call command starts the ppp0 process, and unless I want to terminate that process, I can't run the ip route command IN THE SAME SCRIPT on startup.

Can I:

(1) thread these two commands somehow?

(2) write three scripts; a controller script, the pppd script, and the ip route script?

(3) Do this without being all kludgy?

Answer (score 1):

can't you just put the pppd process into the background like

```
function is_pppd_working {
    # do some test to check pppd is doing what it's meant to
}

function setup_route {
    # do your ip route stuff
}

pppd > somelogfile.log 2>&1 &
sleep 5
PPD_IS_WORKING=$(is_pppd_working)
if [ ${PPD_IS_WORKING} ]
then
    setup_route
else
    # uh oh!!
fi
```

Comment: here's what I've done: `#!/bin/bash
pppd call VPNname > /home/user/Dropbox/logvpnerrors.log 2>&1 &
sleep 5
PPD_IS_WORKING=$(is_pppd_working)
if [ ${PPD_IS_WORKING} ]
then
    setup_route
else
    # todo
function is_pppd_working {
        IFCONFIG="/sbin/ifconfig $ppp0"
        ISIT=`$IFCONFIG | grep "UP" | wc -l`;
        test $ISIT -gt 0;
}
function setup_route {
    ip route add [IPROUTE] dev ppp0
}

fi
`

Comment: So, my question is, why am I getting an unknown command error for is_pppd_working?

Comment: declare the functions ahead of use